# Div Css Menu with images

Tags: html, css, menu

On the link to the demo:

- How can I have the sub-menu list display top-left of the blue border?
- On the sub-menu, for each list item, how can I update the image on hover?

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/king2525/dzw7gnud/8/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav1">
    <a1 href="#">GALAXY S</a>
</div>    
<div id="nav2">
    <a1 href="#">GALAXY A</a>
</div>

<div id="section5">
    <div id="left1">
       <a href="#">GALAXY S6 Edge</a>
       <a href="#">GALAXY S6</a>
       <a href="#">GALAXY S5</a>
       <a href="#">GALAXY S4 Mini</a>
       <a href="#">GALAXY S3 Mini VE</a>
    </div>
          <div id="right1">
             <p><img src="http://www.samsung.com/uk/next/img/estore-recommend-images/mobiles/S6edgegreen.jpg" alt=""></img>
             <a href="">GALAXY S6 Edge information</a></p>
          </div>    
</div>

<div id="section6">
    <div id="left1">
       <a href="">GALAXY A5</a>
       <a href="">GALAXY A3</a>
    </div>
          <div id="right1">
              <p><img src="http://www.samsung.com/uk/next/img/estore-recommend-images/mobiles/S6flatgold.jpg" alt=""></img></p>
          </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have so many errors in your code - even in the absolute basics - I don't even know where to start. I suggest you learn the very basics of HTML and CSS before you try to build stuff like that. If that is not an option, you will have to pay someone to code for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not a coder.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question,

remove `display: inline-block;` from

```
#left1, #right1 {
  width: 49%;
}
```

Instead add `float:left;`

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/dzw7gnud/10/)

Comment: And regarding the 2nd question..that may be too much difficult..why dont you use `ul` and `li` to create such a structure..

Comment: You could at least have corrected the worst errors in his code (duplicate ids `#left1` and `#right1`, non-existent `<a1>` HTML element (but closed with `</a>`), omitted semi-colon in his CSS code) if you consider answering and linking to an updated fiddle.